# Executing a service automatically or a script on init without a init system or cron

Tags: linux, cron

Little background: I have this Synology server with Linux that is running Docker Images. There is one docker image that has a ton of content already within and I cannot recreate it, so basically is wrongly working as a VM. Moreover I cannot edit the Dockerfile because in Synology servers things are a little screwed by the interface making this really difficult to maintain (they create automatic readonly Dockerfiles in a hidden folder not meant to be updated)

The problem is since docker doesn't have an init system + cron service is not activated, I would like to find out a way to activate cron service after startup.

The only idea I've found is faking one of the executables that are already running on boot, for example, apache2, and creating there a script that executes, the real apache2 service + cron service.

I know it's a very weird idea, but I cannot think on any alternative, and this is why I'm asking for your help, to find something more elegant.